# Redirect Loops Problems

Tags: permalinks, customization

I don't know what happened actually. Yesterday, it was just working fine. I recalled what I did to put me in this difficult situation this morning.

Yesterday, I was just editing posts with PhpMyAdmin.

Well, anyway, I disabled all plugin and find out what is not working. It's the Plugin Custom Permalinks.

**My problem is that I have about hundred videos in youtube, and each video is given with Custom Permalink set. I want to keep the Custom Permalink Plugin and get rid with Redirect Loop Problems.**

I now disable my Custom Permalink Plugin and everything work as it is. But this of course is not a good solution.

Please help. If you need whatever codes and details plugin lists, please let me know.

Comment: Editing posts with phpmyadmin... why?

Comment: My youtube video used to keep showing on top of all element. I add the wmode="opaque" to all post with video embeddment.

Comment: You should *never* use the youtube embed code, use oembed instead

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would say, revert to a backup.

Then, never use PHPMyAdmin to edit posts, in fact, uninstall PHPMyAdmin, and use a tool like mysql workbench or query browser

Finally, never use youtube embed codes, to correctly embed a youtube video, put the URL to that video in your post on its own line ( just the URL, make sure it is not a hyperlink ), then save. When viewed on the frontend, the user will not see the youtube URL, they will see a youtube embed autogenerated by the OEmbed API.

For your infinite redirect loop I will need more information, including examples, and a readout of the meta for an example post with its associated URL, and desired redirected URL

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't revert to a backup right now. My last backup is very far from my present work now, cause I haven't often enough.

Comment: For example, my problems is, I have a Custom permalink plugin that store a permalink in a custom field,  field name="Custom Permalink" and field value="math_exercise", for example. Now, if I activated the plugin, it will cause redirected problems and the pages failed to show up. If I deactivated the plugin,  I have so many incoming links issues I have to fixed. For example, I have some video in youtube which link to my pages.

Comment: Please help. If you were able to help, I would refer you to a wp questions cause I have offered some reward (though not a lot) there and I will vote you up for your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, thanks very much for the information of how to correctly embed video. But I don't want it to show on top of other element. How do I put something like wmode="opaque" into work to send the video to the bottom ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-prevent-youtube-oembed-from-overriding-your-wordpress-content/

Comment: Again can you provide actual examples? I can't debug a redirect loop without seeing the redirect loop itself. Also you know you can edit the slugs of posts? You might be better off with the redirection plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Please specify what examples am I supposed to provide. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah you are right! I now know I can configure post name ( I guess the same effect as slug cause I set permalink structure to postname now)

Comment: I have follow up question about how to pull custom field value to post name. I guessed I have to start another post right?

Comment: The youtube solution is cool by the way. I will give it a shot!

Comment: Yes that would be a follow up question

Comment: Also you have not provided links to an example that demonstrates your problem, rather you just 'described' the example, rather than showing it

Comment: Sorry. I know what I was supposed to do now. Thanks so much for your explanation. Anyway, it's not my question now. I have sorted that out without that plugin.

Comment: Can you please post your solution? Anyone else with teh same problem who comes here won't be very happy to find a "Hey I fixed it but I'm not going to tell you how"